# How can I store the output of a mysql command into variables using the shell?

Tags: mysql, shell

I am using this command:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword database -e "select distinct entityName,entitySource from AccessControl"
```

The output is like this:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+
| entityName            | entitySource |
+-----------------------+--------------+
| low                   | Native       |
| high                  | Native       |
| All Groups            | AD           |
| Help Ser vices Group  | AD           |
| DEFAULT_USER_GROUP    | Native       |
| SYSTEM                | Native       |
| DEFAULT_BA_USER_GROUP | Native       |
| soUsersGrp            | Native       |
+-----------------------+--------------+
```

My question is: how can I dynamically create an array of variables to store the values `entityName` and `entitySource`? What I need to use is use every value of entityName and entitySource to update another table.

Earlier I was trying to store the output in a file and access each line using awk, but that doesn't help because one line may contain multiple words.

Comment: Why not use some other script language like ruby/python/php? It will be much simple.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  Setting an environment variable with PHP is stupid simple: http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php. Just write as small PHP script and execute it from the shell.

Comment: yeah i know, it would have been simpler in C...but i have to do that in this only..

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this can be done. I'd like to second the idea that piping mysql to mysql in the shell is awkward, but I understand why it might need to be done (such as when piping `mysql` to `psql` or whatever).

```
mysql -qrsNB -u user -p password database \
    -e "select distinct entityName,entitySource from AccessControl" | \ 
        while read record; do
            NAME="`echo $record|cut -d' ' -f 1`"       # that's a tab delimiter
            SOURCE="`echo $record|cut -d'   ' -f 2`"   # also a tab delimiter 
            # your command with $NAME and $SOURCE goes here ... 
            COMMAND="select trousers from namesforpants where entityName='${NAME}'" # ...
            echo $COMMAND | mysql # flags ...
        done
```

the `-rs` flags trim your output down so that you don't have to grok that table thing it gives you, `-q` asks that the result not be buffered, `-B` asks for batch mode, and `-N` asks to not have column names.

What you do with those variables is up to you; probably I would compose statements in that loop and feed those to your subsequent process rather than worry about interpolation and quotes as you have mentioned some of your data has spaces in it. Or you can write/append to a file and then feed that to your subsequent process.

As usual, the [manual is your friend](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysql/). I'll be your friend, too, but the manpage is where the answers are to this stuff. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mysql -u user -ppassword database -e "select distinct entityName,entitySource from AccessControl" | while read name source; do
    echo "entityName: $name, entitySource: $source"
done
```

Comment: friend what gave was helpful but it doesnt serve the purpose...because in case where "entityName is All Groups", the variables doesnt store corrct values...output is.... 
entityName: All, entitySource: Groups

Comment: use [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator):   `while IFS=$'\t' read name source; do ...`

Answer (score 0):

### Please check it, I fixed it through `exec`.

```
[wcuser@localhost]$ temp=`exec mysql -h10.10.8.36 --port=3306 -uwcuser -pwcuser@123 paycentral -e "select endVersion from script_execution_detail where releaseNo='Release1.0' and versionPrefix='PS'"|tail -1`

[wcuser@localhost]$ echo $temp
```

### 19